# facebook php, how do you use results paging?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello i am using the Facebook PHP SDK (v.3.1.1)

I don't understand how to use the results paging url.

I want to get a list of ALL my friends, here is my code

```
$friends = $fb->api('/me/friends');
/*  
$friend == Array
(
    [data] => Array
    (
       ...
    ),
    [paging] => Array
    (
        [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?method=GET&access_token=SOMETHING&limit=5000&offset=5000
    )
*/
if (!empty($friends['paging']['next']))
{
    $friends2 = $fb->api($friends['paging']['next']);
    //doesn't work
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The values in the paging results that you get are the actual URL's that you need to request in order to get the next group of results. For example :

```
...
{
      "name": "Adobe Flash", 
      "category": "Software", 
      "id": "14043570633", 
      "created_time": "2008-06-05T17:12:36+0000"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
      "next" :https://graph.facebook.com/{USER_ID}/likes?format=json&limit=5000&offset=5000
}
```

This is the "next" paging result I get when I query my user for the pages I like. If I request this URL it will give me a total of 5000 likes with an offset of 5000 (because I already have sen the first 5000 in the initial request).
Hope this clarifies things! good luck!

Comment: There are many ways..you can do `file_get_contents($paging_url)` or use cURL...in my opinion [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) is the easiest way...

Comment: you could also use the facebook->api function and just add those limit, offset parameters to the call - eg: `$fb->api("/me/likes/?limit=5000&offset=5000");`

Comment: ah so i have to get myself that stupid url, i thought i was supposed to get it using the facebook library somehow, thanks!!!

Comment: anytime @Max4ever! no problem :)

Comment: Facebook now only gives you 100 likes/page even if you request 5000, as of at least Oct 2014, with version 2.1 I believe.

Answer (score 14):

All of the previous responses are valid.

Here is the way I do, to get all the "next" result with the Graph API:

Note that I don't get "previous" results.

```
function FB_GetUserTaggedPhotos($user_id, $fields="source,id") {
    $photos_data = array();
    $offset = 0;
    $limit = 500;

    $data = $GLOBALS["facebook"]->api("/$user_id/photos?limit=$limit&offset=$offset&fields=$fields",'GET');
    $photos_data = array_merge($photos_data, $data["data"]);

    while(in_array("paging", $data) && array_key_exists("next", $data["paging"])) {
        $offset += $limit;
        $data = $GLOBALS["facebook"]->api("/$user_id/photos?limit=$limit&offset=$offset&fields=$fields",'GET');
        $photos_data = array_merge($photos_data, $data["data"]);
    }

    return $photos_data;
}
```

You can change the value of $limit as you want, to get less/more data per call.

Comment: this is a good piece of code, still please do note that  ''' Offset based pagination is not supported for all API calls. To get consistent results, we recommend you to paginate using the previous/next links we return in the response. ''' Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2

Comment: refer this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576211/facebook-graph-api-loop-through-paging

Comment: In my testing of this `in_array('paging', $data)` didn't return true, but `array_key_exists('paging', $data)` did.

Answer (score 5):

I adapted **F2000**'s way of dealing with paging and got following code:

```
// Initialize the Facebook PHP SDK object:
$config = array(
    'appId'      => '123456789012345',
    'secret'     => 'be8024db1579deadbeefbcbe587c0bd8',
    'fileUpload' => false );
$fbApi = new Facebook( $config );

// Retrieve list of user's friends:
$offset  = 0;       // Initial offset
$limit   = 10;      // Maximum number of records per chunk
$friends = array(); // Result array for friend records accumulation

$chunk = $fbApi->api(
    "/me/friends", 'GET',
    array(
        'fields' => 'id,name,gender',
        'offset' => $offset,
        'limit'  => $limit ) );

while ( $chunk['data'] )
{
    $friends = array_merge( $friends, $chunk['data'] );
    $offset += $limit;

    $chunk = $fbApi->api(
        "/me/friends", 'GET',
        array(
            'fields' => 'id,name,gender',
            'offset' => $offset,
            'limit'  => $limit ) );
}

// The $friends array contains all user's friend records at this point.
```

The code seems to work. Optionally, for better reliability, it could try to handle temporary connection problems but I skipped this for code clarity.

I am using *Facebook PHP SDK 3.1.1*

Comment: I know this is two years old, but I just wanted to add: If you use a do while loop instead of a while loop, and put the `$friends = ...` and `$offset += ...` lines after your api call, you can cut out that first api call.

Answer (score 2):

The pagination URLs returned from Facebook are not compatible with its own PHP SDK.

You can extract the information needed by the API from the pagination URLs and pass it to the SDK API.

Use the PHP [parse_url](http://www.php.net/parse_url) function or some string manipulations to extract such information.

*Sample code to retrieve part of my friend list (using `parse_url`)*:

```
$ret = $facebook->api('/me/friends?limit=25');
var_dump($ret);
$next = parse_url($ret['paging']['next']);
$ret = $facebook->api($next['path'] . '?' . $next['query']);
var_dump($ret);
```

Answer (score 2):

Facebook querying with limit and offset pagination wasn't working good not returning all the results, so I made a recursive function using the pagination['next'] fields provided by the API.

The function:

```
function chunk_results($arr,$query)
{   
    global $facebook;
    $chunk = $facebook->api($query);
    if($chunk['data']==null)
    {
        return $arr;
    }   
    else
    {
        foreach($chunk['data'] as $dato)
            $arr['data'][] = $dato;

        return chunk_results($arr,substr($chunk['paging']['next'],26));

    }
}
```

And you can initialize it with an empty array and the query you want to get, like in the following example:

```
chunk_results(array(),"/457568434275922/posts?fields=message")
```

Hope it helps!

PD: My Facebook object is called $facebook

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually use next url directly, Facebook php sdk does not support it, but you could use php standard functions to extract data you need. I used it for facebook search api,
this is the example

`$result = $fb->api('/search', 'GET', $paramsArray );
    $url = parse_url($result['paging']['next']);
    parse_str($url['query'], $nextParams );
    $nextResult = $fb->api('/search', 'GET', $nextParams );`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any answers actually using a Facebook Cursor, so I thought I'd add my solution for getting all of a Page's Leadgen Forms. This should work using any method that returns a Cursor:

```
$params = []; // initial parameters are empty to get the first page
$fields = []; // define the field

while ($leadgen_forms = $account->getLeadGenForms($fields, $params)) {

    foreach ($leadgen_forms as $key => $value) {
        // do stuff
    }   

    $params['after'] = $leadgen_forms->getAfter();
    if (!$params['after']) 
        break;
}
```