# Facebook graph API loop through paging

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, paging, facebook-php-sdk

So I was working with this script to loop through the events from a given page. Suddenly I find it doesn't work anymore :(

I have a feeling it could be a bug, because if you pick any page, view events with an access_token, you can't get any data back for the "next" paginated URL. e.g. try https://graph.facebook.com/evenightclub/events in apigee.com

Any ideas?

($fid is the page object id)

```
    try {
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => '<removed>',
      'secret' => '<removed>',
    ));
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

    $events_data = array();
    $offset = 0;
    $limit = 5000;  
    $params = array('access_token' => $access_token);

    //fetch events from Facebook API
    $data = $facebook->api("$fid/events/?limit=$limit&offset=$offset", $params);
    $events_data = array_merge($events_data, $data["data"]);

    //loop through pages to return all results
    while(in_array("paging", $data) && array_key_exists("next", $data["paging"])) {
        $offset += $limit;
        $data = $facebook->api("$fid/events/?limit=$limit&offset=$offset", $params);
        $events_data = array_merge($events_data, $data["data"]);
    }}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code works for me, the only thing that I did is to make sure that count($data["data"]) > 0 before merging it with the existing information. So it looks like this:

```
//loop through pages to return all results
while(in_array("paging", $data) && array_key_exists("next", $data["paging"])) {
    $offset += $limit;
    $data = $facebook->api("$fid/events/?limit=$limit&offset=$offset", $params);
    // make sure we do not merge with an empty array
    if (count($data["data"]) > 0){
        $events_data = array_merge($events_data, $data["data"]);
    } else {
        // if the data entry is empty, we have reached the end, exit the while loop
        break;
    }
}}
```

Comment: Heh, I was just searching for this same problem. Stumbled across this and thought "wow, this is exactly what I'm after". Scroll up a bit and look at the OP, "hmm, I think I've seen this code before", looks at the username, "huh". Your answer works perfectly by the way, apologies for not marking it a year ago :)

Comment: don't you have to set offset like this:  $offset += count($data["data"]) , in case the number of actual items returned is less than $limit?  in this case, i don't think FB is return 5,000 items on every call.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this method to get all Facebook posts by user.

```
$appId = env('FBAPP_ID');
$appSecret = env('FBAPP_SECRET_KEY');
$fb = new Facebook([
        'app_id' => $appId,
        'app_secret' => $appSecret,
        'default_graph_version' => 'v3.3'
]);
```

Token received after user allow my app to get his/her profile

```
$access_token = $args['token'];//you need to pass here your token
```

Get user detail

```
try {
            // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
            $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,birthday,email,location,picture', $access_token);
        } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
        $graphUser = $response->getGraphUser();

        $fb_uid = $graphUser['id'];
```

Now try to get user posts

```
try {
    $fields = "id,message,picture,name,description,type,icon,created_time,from,object_id,attachments,source,full_picture";
    $userFeed = $fb->get("/$fb_uid/posts?fields={$fields}&limit=5", $access_token);
    $feedBody = $userFeed->getDecodedBody();
    $feedData = $feedBody["data"];
    if (isset($feedBody['paging']) && $feedBody['paging']['next']) {
        $nextPageData = $this->getNextPageFbPost($feedBody['paging']['next']);
        while ($nextPageData['paging'] && $nextPageData['paging']['next']) {
            $nextPageData = $this->getNextPageFbPost($nextPageData['paging']['next']);
            if (count($nextPageData["data"]) > 0) {
                $feedData = array_merge($feedData, $nextPageData["data"]);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
} catch (FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
} catch (FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}

foreach ($feedData as $postData) {
      print_r($postData);
}

  function getNextPageFbPost($url)
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, '');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        $raw_xml = curl_exec($curl);
        $result = json_decode($raw_xml, true);
        return $result;
    }
```