# FB Request Access to Public Feed API - Custom Results?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

1) When accessing the page, via Facebook PHP SDK:

```
$pagefeed = $facebook->api("/" . $pageid . "/feed?limit=200");
```

I see only 25 results - I searched the official documentation and it said by default it limits to 25 recent posts and that on setting limit field, it will give you more than 25 results (has to be less than 250). I'm using 200. When I `var_dump($pagefeed)` - it shows all the user data (including comments, people's names who liked the post, etc.) - How can I get last 200 posts for a page only?

2) Now, I want to search a page for keyword - Is there a way? I do not wish to use FQL. Is there any such field? If yes, (even if it's FQL) - Can you explain a bit?

Comment: Killed search engine results :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) That is NOT the "Public Feed API", that´s only the Page Feed API. Results are limited to 25 entries, you need to implement paging in order to get more results: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#paging - just use the "next" value in the result for the next API call to get the next batch:

```
$pagefeed = $facebook->api($next_api_url);
```

2) There is no keyword search for pages, the only way is to get ALL entries (see above) and do the searching with PHP. FQL is deprecated and does not work in newer Apps anymore.

Comment: Are you implying this?

if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
 $page = $_GET['page'];
 $cur_page = $page;
 $offset = $page * 25;
 $nextpage = $page + 1;

} else {
 $page = 0;
 $cur_page = $page;
 $offset = $page * 25;
 $nextpage = $page + 1;
 $prevPage = $cur_page;
}
if ($cur_page > 0) {
 $prevPage = $cur_page - 1;
} else {
 $prevPage = 0;
}
$pf = $facebook->api("/" . $pageid . "/feed?limit=25&offset=" . $offset);



 markup:

 <a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $nextpage;?>">Next </a>
                     <a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $prevPage;?>">Previous</a>

How it will load next set of data?

Comment: no, definitely not, but you really should not post code in comments, it´s very hard to read...please take a look at the link i posted.

Comment: I did. But I'm asking this 

[paging] => Array - Previous and Next is returned in the data object that is returned from facebook. Do I directly put in the paginators? Or Do I have to format with until and since? Please post an example if possible. Many thanks!

Comment: just use the value of the "next" field as new api call. everything you need is in that field already, just check debug it in your result.

Comment: How do I pass it to next page? I have two links at bottom of my page Previous and Next. When I click next, I'd like for next 25 results to load. I just need that. Please help!

Comment: not sure what you want to know, i´ve added a code example in my answer. just use the value of "next" in another api call to get the next 25 entries.

Comment: Exactly! 
I've done that already, the problem is $facebook->api($next_api_url) you say - returns graph.facebook.com/page/nextvalues
whereas $facebook->api already adds graph.facebook.com and returns an data object.
I'm getting a URL in the var_dump($pagefeed) 
When I go to that URL, I see all the NEXT page data. I want that data should be fetched in the first place, not the URL. 
Here they say, use file_get_contents()  - but it's not helpful.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211177/facebook-php-how-do-you-use-results-paging

Can you please suggest something! I'm really in need of some help

Comment: yeah, you just need to remove graph.facebook.com then. also, file_get_contents is not good, the facebook sdk uses curl and that is what you should too if you don´t use the sdk.

Comment: you can´t get the data instead of the next link. you MUST use pagination and extra calls if you want to get more entries.

Comment: I am using pagination but how to pass result to the next page? If I'm on page 4 how do I not start all over again but take data from 25*4 = 100th entry forth?

Comment: what result? it´s as simple as using the next url in the call, and you will get the next batch of entries. you don´t need to pass anything. if you are on page 4, use the "next" string in the result of page 4 for the next batch. it´s really simple, and there´s nothing else to explain, i am afraid.